# Compiling Cocos2d-x project on both Linux and OSX

Tags: android, macos, cocos2d-x-3.0

I originally started developing a game on Linux and I successfully had it running on an Android device. I then switched to developing on a Mac, and now I am getting an error when compiling. It is likely caused by absolute file paths that were on my Linux machine.

Here are the errors: (slightly edited for clarity)

```
Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in /Users/MY_MAC_USER/cocos2d/folder-on-mac/MyGameName/frameworks/runtime-src/proj.android/../../cocos2d-x/cocos/scripting/js-bindings/proj.android/Android.mk for module cocos2d_js_static    
Android NDK:   \    
make: Entering directory `/Users/MY_MAC_USER/cocos2d/folder-on-mac/MyGameName/frameworks/runtime-src/proj.android'
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/MY_LINUX_USER/cocos2d/projects/folder_on_linux/MyGameName/frameworks/runtime-src/proj.android/../../cocos2d-x/cocos/scripting/js-bindings/proj.android/../auto/jsb_cocos2dx_3d_auto.cpp', needed by `obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/cocos2d_js_static/__/auto/jsb_cocos2dx_3d_auto.o'.  Stop.
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: Leaving directory `/Users/MY_MAC_USER/cocos2d/folder-on-mac/MyGameName/frameworks/runtime-src/proj.android'
```

I could probably get this working by updating all the file paths, but this just seems like a really messy way of doing things.

I don't entirely understand what files are being generated by cocos2d-x. It seems like these paths must have been generated when I ran `cocos new` on my linux machine. This seems strange, considering `$PATH` variables are used when running `cocos compile`.

Is there any way I can setup these paths to also be generated from a `$PATH` variable before compiling?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a way to setup all these paths easily. Just download the cocos2d-x folder from the official website. After extracting, just run the setup.py as below, which is inside the cocos2d-x framework that you just downloaded.

`./setup.py`

Now it will ask you to enter the paths for the following and automatically set environment variables for them:

- android-sdk
- android-ndk
- apache-ant

Comment: I did initially run `./setup.py` on both machines, and compilation works fine if a create a new project on my Mac. The paths created by `./setup.py` may be used when compiling, but I think some paths must end up hardcoded in the files generated by `cocos new`.